# C# setter/getter of two variables

Tags: c#, setter, getter, getter-setter

Is there an option to do one setter/getter for two variables? Or the only option are two separate setter/getter's like this:

```
int var1;
int var2;

public int var1 
    {
    get { return var1; }
    set { var1 = value; }
    }

public int var2 
    {
    get { return var2; }
    set { var2 = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what syntax you're imagining?  I'm not sure I understand what it is you can't do.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? Your question does not make sense.

Comment: I need to write setters and getters for two integer variables and I don't know if this is the only way to do that, or is there a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
public int var1 { get;set;}

public int var2 { get;set;}
```

Answer (score 3):

"one setter/getter for two variables" - there no syntax to simplify that (you can use automatic properties for single value only).

It can be implemented with wrapping these variables into class and using single property to get/set. I.e. using built in `Tuple` class:

```
var1;
int var2;

public Tuple<int,int> BothVars
{
  get { return Tuple.Create(var1,var2); }
  set { 
       var1 = value.Item1;
       var2 = value.Item2;
      }
}
```